# write and test a method PrintSquare

Tags: recursion

Write and test a method printSquares that has an integer parameter n, and prints the squares of the integers from 1 to n, separated by commas. It should print the squares of the odd integers in descending order first and then following with the squares of the even integers in ascending order. It does not print a newline character. It should throw an IllegalArgumentException if the specified integer is less than 1.     For example:        printSquares(4) should print 9, 1, 4, 16        printSquares(1) should print 1      printSquares(7) should print 49, 25, 9, 1, 4, 16

Comment: Sounds like a fun homework problem. Why are you sharing it with us?

Comment: Probably not on topic for this forum, but forgetting that...  What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

there you go, i hope your teacher is ok with this (this will throw exceptions if you enter negetive numbers and it adds a useless comma at the end which i can fix if it really bothers you)

```
    public static void printOrder(int n) {
        decOrderOdd(n);
        acsOrderEven(1, n);
    }
    public static void decOrderOdd(int n) {
        if (n > 0)
        {
            if (n%2 == 1)
            {
                System.out.print(n*n + ", ");
                decOrderOdd(n-2);
            }
            if (n%2 == 0)
                decOrderOdd(n-1);
        }
    }

    public static void acsOrderEven(int n, int target) {
        if (n <= target)
        {
            if (n%2 == 0)
            {
                System.out.print(n*n + ", ");
                acsOrderEven(n + 2, target);
            }
            if (n%2 == 1)
                acsOrderEven(n+1, target);
        }
    }
```